# Xpage control shows the readonly mode even if it is false

Tags: xpages

Here is the snippet

```
<xp:repeat id="agendaRepeat" rows="30" var="agenda" indexVar="agendaIndex">

        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var r = document1.getItemValue("AgendaHeading");
return (typeof r == 'string') ? [r] : r;}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:inputHidden id="agendaGuideReferenceHiddenRepeat" />


                <xp:inputText id="agendaGuideHeaderInput"
                    styleClass="agendaGuideHeaderInput" value="#{agenda}">

<!-- inputTextarea1 DOES NOT WORK -->               
                        <xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea1"
                            styleClass="agendaGuideSubtextInput"
                            value="#{javascript:document1.getItemValue('AgendaText').get(agendaIndex)}"
                            readonly="false">

                        </xp:inputTextarea>

</xp:repeat>
```

the control is always showing in readonly, and IF I bind it like following

```
document1.AgendaText[index]
```

then it shows fine, as it is in the repeat control so I can't do this because it keeps showing me an exception:

```
Error getting property '0' from bean of type java.lang.String
```

because there has to be at least 2 items in the field to show... I am using multivalue fields...

SO WHY IT DOES NOT SHOW AS AN EDITABLE FIELD IF I CHOOSE THE FIRST OPTION. 
I will be very thankful

Comment: Could you add the repeat control to the code snippet also.

Comment: Only EL can do input bindings, SSJS cannot.  Are you repeating over the items using a repeat?

Comment: just added more snippet.. yes it is repeat

Comment: at least it should not set the readonly attr to true???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Toby mentioned in the Comments, input field are never editable when you use SSJS as value for them. You have to use expression language.

When you use expression language and the item is empty or has only one value, you are not able to address it with the index.

To avoid the error above and have an editable field, you can place two inputTextareas in your repeat, one is binded to "document1.AgendaText[agendaIndex]"  and the other is binded to "document1.AgendaText". You can then use the rendered property to use the corresponding inputTextareas depending if it's a multi or single value item (see sample code below).

Sample Code:

```
<xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea_multiValue" styleClass="agendaGuideSubtextInput" readonly="false">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Elements( document1.getItemValue('AgendaText') ) > 1;}]]></xp:this.rendered>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{document1.AgendaText[agendaIndex]}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:inputTextarea>

<xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea_singleValue" value="#{document1.AgendaText}" styleClass="agendaGuideSubtextInput" readonly="false">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Elements( document1.getItemValue('AgendaText') ) <= 1;}]]></xp:this.rendered>
</xp:inputTextarea>
```